# Is TCP Reset (RST) two way?

Tags: sockets, tcp

I have a client-server (Java) application using persistent TCP connections, but sometimes the Server receives `java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer` exception when trying to write on the socket, however I don't see any error in the Client log.

This RST is probably caused by an intermediate proxy/router, but if that's the case, should this be seen on the client as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the RST is sent by the client, it can be seen on it using a packet sniffer such as [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). However, it won't show up in any user-level sockets since it's sent by the OS as a response to various erroneous inputs (such as connection attempts to a closed port).

If the RST is sent by the network, then it's pretending to be the client to sever the connection. It can do so in one direction, or in both of them. In that case, the client might not see anything, except for a RST sent by the actual server when the client continues to send data to a connection it perceives as open, while the server sees it as closed.

Try capturing the traffic on both the server and the client, see where the resets are coming from.

Comment: Thanks, so does this mean that if there's a router between the nodes and the router RSTs the connection, this will be seen only by the node that tried to write; the other node has to read/write in order to see the connection termination even if it's the server-side?

Comment: TCP RST messages are supposed to be sent from tcp endpoints - either the client or the server. The network (in theory) has no business sending them. To send a TCP RST that will be received by the server, the network has to pretend to be the client. To send one to the client, it has to pretend to be the server.

However, if the RST was sent to only one side, the other machine will try to continue the TCP session, and receive a real RST from the second machine, which already closed the connection.